Why can some pending jobs on runAI be suspended while other pending jobs cannot be suspended?
Some pending jobs on runAI can be suspended e.g.:

and some pending jobs cannot be suspended e.g.:

Why can some pending jobs on runAI be suspended while other pending jobs cannot be suspended?
